# Where to set the locks in apply pandas with multithreading?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pandas, multiprocessing, apply

I am trying to asynchronously read and write from a pandas df with an apply function. For this purpose I am using the `multithreading.dummy` package. Since I am doing read and write simultaneously (multithreaded) on my df, I am using `multiprocessing.Lock()` so that no more than one `thread` can edit the df at the a given time. However I am a bit confused to where I should be adding a `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()`with an `apply` function in `pandas`. I have tried doing as per below, however, it seems that doing as so the entire process becomes `synchronous`, so it defeats the whole purpose of multithreading.

```
self._lock.acquire()
to_df[col_name] = to_df.apply(lambda row: getattr(Object(row['col_1'], 
                                                           row['col_2'],
                                                           row['col_3']), 
                                                          someattribute), axis=1)
self._lock.release()
```

Note: In my case I have to be doing `getattr`. `someattribute` is simply a `@property` in `Object`. Object takes 3 arguments, which some from rows 1,2,3 from my df.

Comment: What is the initial purpose to do it asynchronously? In Python (CPython) threads are used for I/O bound operations (due to GIL) and processes are used for CPU-bound operations.

Comment: @ Poolka so the pandas I am using contains columns of URLs, for each one of the URLs, it's making calls to various places, then returns information back to the df

Comment: Then change the design - use threads and queues to send URLs to working threads and information back to main thread to combine it into df. Locks are not needed.

Comment: @Poolka how would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There 2 possible solutions. 1 - locks. 2 - queues. Code below is just a skeleton, it may contain typos/errors and cannot be used as is.

First. Locks where they actually needed:

```
def method_to_process_url(df):

    lock.acquire()
    url = df.loc[some_idx, some_col]
    lock.release()

    info = process_url(url)

    lock.acquire()
    # add info to df
    lock.release()
```

Second. Queues instead of locks:

```
def method_to_process_url(df, url_queue, info_queue):
    for url in url_queue.get():
        info = process_url(url)
        info_queue.put(info)

url_queue = queue.Queue()
# add all urls to process to the url_queue

info_queue = queue.Queue()

# working_thread_1
threading.Thread(
    target=method_to_process_url,
    kwargs={'url_queue': url_queue, 'info_queue': info_queue},
    daemon=True).start()


# more working threads

counter = 0
while counter < amount_of_urls:
    info = info_queue.get():
    # add info to df
    counter += 1
```

In the second case you may even start separate thread for every url without `url_queue` (reasonable if amount of urls is on the order of thousands or less). `counter` is some simple way to stop the program when all urls are processed.

I would use the second approach if you ask me. It is more flexible in my opinion.

Comment: I would mark your answers as correct, however, as I have discovered, pandas are not write safe when threading. Check this out http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#caveats.  Look at the warning under Caveats.

Comment: @callmeGuy It is not a problem at all. Safety in these approaches is achieved by locks/queues (locks are locks, queues are threadsafe). In the second approach pandas dataframe is treated in just one thread.